# ES deleting duplicates

Tags: java, elasticsearch, duplicates

I'm currently migrating some data (> 100MM) from Oracle to Elasticsearch.

I'm using the bulk API with is working perfectly, but now I have migrated all data I want to clean up a little by removing the duplicates (generated due problems on the migration process that took like 2 days and I don't want to start over).

I can see all my duplicates with a query like this (using sense):

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggregations": {
    "duplicates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message_id",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I having a lot of problems finding a way to delete those using delete by query, you see, **I need to delete the duplicates leaving one copy**. I mean that if I have 2 records of the message_id XXXX I need to delete just one in order to keep 1 in the ES.

Do you know a way to achieve this?

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Is the `message_id` the same as the ES doc ID?

Comment: No, it's different on purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the ID of one document you want to save, you can then use a [Delete by Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) with a [Not Filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html).

For example, if you have 3 documents with doc IDs 1, 2, 3, all documents had the same `messageId` of 13 and you want to save document 1 you can run this query:

```
DELETE /yourIndex/yourType/_query
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "messageId": "13"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "not": {
                    "term": {
                        "_id": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doc 2 and doc 3 will be deleted and doc 1 will still be present in the index. Test this out locally first.

Comment: Thanks, this is more efficient when duplicates are more than twice.

Comment: This is working, a little slow but fine, I supposed there is no better way :(

Comment: Is the query slow, or is is slow because you have to run the query for every `messageId`? If it is the later you could delete multiple messageIds in one query.

Comment: The second one, I was iterating over all buckets and then deleting one by one. Last night I modified my program to delete 100 buckets at once ;)

Answer (score 1):

Run a query to find the records that are duplicated, something like:

```
GET {index}/{type}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "message_id": {
        "value": "{message_id_value}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your query will return 2 records, they have the same `message_id` but will have different `_id` fields.  _id is the internal ES identifier.  Once you have that you can delete that identifier:

```
DELETE {index}/{type}/{_id}
```

Comment: Yes I could do this but it's kind a manual thing (maybe I could write a program to execute this but will be slow I think). I have thousands of duplicates, I was trying to find a "delete by query" that can omit 1 record or something like that

Comment: yeah, I've never seen the equivalent of a "DELETE TOP (1)"